# Is there a way to change the Share default permission level to “Read”?

Tags: 2013, default-value, share

When I click “Share” as a Collection admin/site owner, I get a screen where my options are limited to Can Edit and Can View, and the permission choices are Contribute and Read, respectively.

[image: ![Site Owner Share Screen]

When I click on “Share” as a user I get the default of ‘Invite people to Edit”. The drop down to modify this permission level is hidden and requires a user to click show options to modify it to read.

[image]

We have an issue where users are sharing a document but providing access to edit unknowingly. I would like modify this to default to Read to minimize providing higher access than intended.